# Is it possible to run an script when installing a cordova plugin?

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I know when I install a cordova plugin the native files are copied into the platform folder and will be compiled when I build that platform. But is it possible to execute an script to for example download additional binary files, or build custom frameworks?

What I am looking for is a way to specify in `plugin.xml` to execute a particular shell script or install an npm module when the plugin is first installed into a Cordova project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible using the 'cordova plugin add' command (not what they were designed to do) but definitely possible if you use task manager tools like Grunt to automate your process.

You can combine tasks to run in order, such as running your own shell scripts before/after you make a call to install plugins.

Check out npm grunt for more info.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What exactly do you mean by making a call to install the plugin? I will look into grunt to see what I can do. It would be great if you could provide a little code example or a bit more explanation of when and how the grunt task will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

check this:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html

You only have to make a folder, called "after_plugin_add", inside the hooks folder of the project, and add there your script.